# Inheriting from variadic types messes up template member function indentation in Emacs

Tags: c++, linux, emacs

Unpacking `Ts` in inheritance adds extra indentation to template member function `void bar()`. How can I get rid of that extra indentation?

```cpp
template <typename ...Ts>
struct Foo: public Ts...
{
    Foo()
    {
    }

    template <typename U>
        void bar()
    {
    }
};
```

Non-unpacked inheritance works well:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Foo: public T, public U
{
    Foo()
    {
    }

    template <typename S>
    void bar()
    {
    }
};
```

My `.emacs`:

```
; Replace highlighted text
(delete-selection-mode 1)


(defun bb-cpp-style()
  (c-set-style "linux")
  (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
  (setq tab-width 4)
  (setq c-basic-offset 4)

  (c-set-offset 'case-label '+)
  (c-set-offset 'statement-case-intro '+)
  (c-set-offset 'statement-case-open '0)

  (c-set-offset 'inlambda 'c-lineup-inexpr-block) ;
  (c-set-offset 'inline-open '0) ;

)

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'bb-cpp-style)

; treat .h as c++
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.h\\'" . c++-mode))
```

**Expected:**

```cpp
template <typename ...Ts>
struct Foo: public Ts...
{
    Foo()
    {
    }

    template <typename U>
    void bar()
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: C++ is very complex. Only a C++ compiler fully understands the structure of C++ source. Emacs is not a C++ compiler. It gets it wrong, occasionally. That's it, there's nothing else to say about it. This is not the only problem. Right now the C++ major mode does not recognize `if constexpr`, either. It is what it is. Hopefully, someday the C++ major mode will improve.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeah, I was hoping in a magic-lisp expression if there's no explicit keyword for it. Unfortunately my Lisp is pretty much exhausted after a copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

The cc-mode syntactic element associated with the offending line is `statement-cont`. You can see the syntactic info with the functions `c-show-syntactic-information` and `c-syntactic-information-on-region`. Maybe there is some issue with how those elements are parsed since that line is given different syntactic designations in your two versions of the code - I dont know.

You could try adding a custom indentation rule for `statement-cont` that says to add no indentation to a `statement-cont` when it isn't an assignment (note: `c-lineup-assignments` doesn't add indentation to continuations following a line with `=` at the end of the line). This is simple:

```
(defun my-lineup-statement (langelem)
  (or (c-lineup-assignments langelem) 0))
```

And call `(c-set-offset 'statement-cont #'my-lineup-statement)` in the buffer to test it out (or add it to your mode hook). That should fix the indent in the case you've shown.

I tested it briefly on a couple files and the only other side-effect of this change I noticed was that it removed the indentation of the continued statement following a naked `=`, as in

```
int x =
1;  // before adding 'my-lineup-assignments this usually indented (depending on chosen c style)
```

There might be other cases where you want `statement-cont` elements to get indented.

Comment: Thanks @Rorschach, it works as you described. Unfortunately I put the RHS expression to new line way more often than using variadic inheritance, so the sacrifice outweighs the advantage for me in this case. But really appreciate your effort, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yea, it's just a starting point. For example, if you wanted to handle the indentation following the dangling '=' you could snipe the piece of code from `c-lineup-assignments` that checks for that and add it into the lineup function, returning `nil` and falling back to `'++` like linux style. I noticed `c++-ts-mode` doesn't currently indent that line either, but with that mode it is really simple to add a rule to do so.

Comment: I'm afraid that's beyond my knowledge ;-) Lisp is an uncharted territory to me.